# grails - AbstractConfigHelper - Assertion failed

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have grails application. It was written in grails 1.3.7 and later upgraded to grails 2.2.4. I get the following error every time I run it for the first time (for example after clean install on another computer or after I delete project folder in .grails dir):

```
Caused by IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this expression must be true
->>  340 | newInstance in org.grails.plugin.config.AbstractConfigHelper$ConfigObjectProxy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    111 | doCall    in org.grails.plugin.config.DefaultConfigHelper$_enhanceConfigObjectClass_closure3
|      1 | run . . . in Script1
|    160 | afterPropertiesSet in grails.plugin.transaction.handling.TransactionHandlingPostProcessor
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I got rid of it by changing:

```
Assert.isTrue(interfaces.remove(GroovyObject.class));
```

to

```
if (interfaces.contains(GroovyObject.class)) {
    Assert.isTrue(interfaces.remove(GroovyObject.class));
}
```

in AbstractConfigHelper.java.

It seems unharmfull and everything works fine since then, but I'd rather know what was the problem in the first place and if I messed up something.

It happens both on windows and linux. We use

- plugin-config:0.1.5
- transaction-handling:0.1.3
- joda-time:1.4
- quartz:1.0-RC9
- spring-security-core:1.2.7.3

(I don't think other plugins have anything to do with this problem).

Do any of you know what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be upgrading the plugins as well, or at least check whether they are compatible with updated version of Grails or not. Start with [plugin-config](http://grails.org/plugin/plugin-config)

From plugin-config's excerpts:

```
//For Grails 2.x
plugins {
   compile ':plugin-config:0.2.0'
}
```

I think the above plugin upgrade will resolve the issue. I also hope you would not need `transaction-handling` plugin anymore. But would positively suggest upgrading others.

Comment: Wow, how could I have missed that. Thank you for help and hint on transaction-handling - maybe we really don't need it anymore, but I have to read more about isolation levels in new grails. Thanks again!